# Why the below piece of code is not crashing , though i have deleted the object?

Tags: c++

```
class object
{
  public:
    void check()
    {
      std::cout<<"I am doing ok..."<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
  object *p = new object;
  p->check();
  delete p;
  p->check();
  delete p;
  p->check();
}
```

**EDIT**:
Gurus, i am confused by many of the statements "it may crash or may not".. why isnt there a standard to say, this how we deal with a block of memory that is deleted using 'delete operator'..? Any inputs ?

Comment: Gurus, i am confused by many of the statements "it may crash or may not".. why isnt there a standard to say, this how we deal with a block of memory that is deleted using 'delete operator'..?  Any inputs ?

Comment: It "may or may not" crash because the behaviour is undefined and dependent on the compiler, operating system and what else is going on. Basically, the delete just marks the pointer as being available again. Nothing explicit is done to the memory being pointed at, so you can get away with using it if nothing else has changed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because what it actually looks like after the compiler has had its way, is something like this:

```
object::check( object* this )
{
     // do stuff without using this
}

int main()
{        
     object *p = new object;
     object::check( p );
     delete p;
     object::check( p );
     delete p;
     object::check( p );
 }
```

Since you're not touching "this", you don't actually access any bad memory.

Although, deleting p twice should be able to cause a crash:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.2

Comment: Regarding the deleting 2x possibly causing a crash... yep, that's why I typically set "p" to 0 after deleting... a) so I know that it doesn't point an object anymore and b) because it's safe to call delete on a null pointer.

Comment: Many codebases I've seen have had something like a "#define SAFE_DELETE(x) delete x, x = NULL" macro, or better yet template, for this reason.  This is one of the few places I like the comma operator -- the delete and NULL assign should "belong" to the same statement in most cases, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 7):

Because the function is not doing anything with the object's member data or the `this` pointer.

It's like calling a function

```
void check(object *self)
{
  std::cout<<"I am doing ok..."<<std::endl;
}
```

with an invalid pointer as the `self` argument.

There is a double delete though, which can crash in some environments.

Comment: It's even funnier than that.
This compiles & runs nicely:

#include <iostream>                                                             
using namespace std;

class object {
    public:
        void check() {
            cout << "I am doing ok..." << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    object *p = (object*)0;
    p->check();
    return 0;
}

$ g++ -o t t.cc
$ $ ./t
I am doing ok...
$

:) You don't actually have to have an object to call this method!

cheers,
h.

Comment: Yes because methods are not part of the object. Methods are part of the class. Try recalling the OO principles. Attributes and Behavior. Attributes are associated with the objects and Behavior are Class-level. All objects behave in the same way. Behind the scenes, all objects are stored in a sort of a function table and a call to a function is just a jump of instruction pointer to the function's starting address. For more details, view my answer to this question.

Comment: sorry a type in the above link, all functions are stored in a function table, not objects.

Comment: @Aamir: Non-virtual functions are not stored in any table, they are resolved at link time. Virtual functions are resolved at runtime using the object's vtable.

Comment: @laalto: Yes, you are right. I sort of tried to simplify it for him by not going into deeper details.

Comment: @Aamir: Yes but the details in this case are relevant since the function is non-virtual and therefore statically linked. If it was a virtual function, calling it could have crashed because the vtable is accessed through the object.

Answer (score 7):

Delete only deallocates memory and makes it available back to the heap.

The value of the pointer is undefined after delete has been called, so it may crash it may not.

A programming tip I use to reduce programming errors is to after a delete, set the pointer to NULL.  In this way, you know you are not accidently using a pointer after it's been deleted.

Comment: You can still use the pointer. A check has to be made for NULL, but I guess that's what you meant.

Comment: A true statment but completely unappliccable to this "issue".

Comment: +1 for mentioning setting pointer to NULL.  Great when debugging too because deleted pointers don't look like they could still be valid.

Comment: The value of the pointer is not undefined, it is exactly the same as is was prior to delete.

Comment: After deleting, the pointer refers to deallocated storage and becomes invalid. What that means precisely isn't defined yet: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#312 .

Answer (score 5):

You can do the same with nil pointers, just as long as you never access the state of the class instance:

```
class object
{
  public:
    void check()
    {
      std::cout<<"I am doing ok..."<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
  object *p = 0;
  p->check();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's even funnier than that.
This compiles & runs nicely:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class object {
    public:
      void check() {
          cout << "I am doing ok..." << endl;
      }
};

int main() {
   object *p = (object*)0;
   p->check();
   return 0;
}
```

On to the shell:

```
$ g++ -o t t.cc
$ ./t
I am doing ok...
$
```

:) You don't actually have to have an object to call this method!
cheers, h

Answer (score 2):

Even if the method call was using the this pointer it would not be guaranteed to crash. The pointer p  when deleted is not being zeroed so is still pointing to the same address in memory. Depending on the implementation of new/delete and the heap manager this memory might not even be resused so the use of p may still continue to work even though the memory has been released.

Answer (score 1):

1) Depends on compiler, on Mac OS with gcc 4.0.1:

```
g++ -Wall -g -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -o x main.o 
./x
I am doing ok ...
I am doing ok ...
x(5857) malloc: *** error for object 0x100150: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
I am doing ok ...
```

Double free is causing problems.

2) Generally deleting pointer that has already been deleted is not defined, you should always set pointer to 0 after deleting, calling delete on pointer with value 0 is allowed.

3) The reason it can still print the string is that the pointer still points to memory that was now freed, but I would assume that only the pointer is reclaimed e.g. returned to free pool for reuse, the memory is not overwritten or nulled so if you dereference the pointer you still get the original values, unless the memory is reused in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

delete does not set p to null so it still points to the memory location. It depends on implementation of new/delete but usually delete only marks that part of memory as available for any new allocations.

Its like when you delete a file off your hardrive. The file system simply marks that area as available. The file data exists and can still be recovered as long as you don't do new writes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the environment (platform/compiler)...
This at least gives unexpected behaviour.
I think you are lucky that it doesn't crash in your case ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To add a little to what others have said, try using a member variable of your class inside the check() method and then see what happens.

Function calling in case of classes is similar to normal function calling except for one little difference. The arguments are pushed on stack in both cases but in case of a function call of an object, 'this' is pushed on to the stack as the first argument. This 'this' is used inside function to access the member variables. Since you are not accessing any member variables, it is working. And yes, it can work even if you access member variables but you will get unexpected behavior because compiler is free to use the memory that was allocated to 'p'. As soon as compiler will utilize that memory, you will start getting crashes. For example, if you declare further variables after deleting before reusing 'p', it might crash.

Edit: Furthermore, if your method is not accessing any member variable, then it is a definite candidate to be a static method.

Comment: Bro i changed the code like this, still it doesnt crash :

class object
{
  int p;
  public:
    object()
    {
      p = 100;
    }
    void check()
    {
      std::cout<<"p = "<<p<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"I am doing ok..."<<std::endl;
    }
};

>> ./test
p = 100
I am doing ok...
p = 100
I am doing ok...
p = 100
I am doing ok...

Comment: As I explained earlier, deleting 'p' simply means that memory is free to be used for compiler. Internally, the place to which pointer 'p' is pointing is still holding a valid address. Try declaring some more pointer variables before reusing 'p' and it might crash. This will give you unexpected behavior. Nobody can tell you that when exactly it will crash.