# Why it works? C++ memory management

Tags: c++, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why the below piece of code is not crashing , though i have deleted the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006214/why-the-below-piece-of-code-is-not-crashing-though-i-have-deleted-the-object)

Today i found out that i know nothing about C++ memory management. Please take a look at this piece of code:

```
class A
{
 public:
     A(){std::cout << "constructor called" << this << std::endl;}
    ~A(){std::cout << "destructor called" << this << std::endl;}
      void test (){std::cout << "test" << this << std::endl;}
 };

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

A *aa = new A();

delete aa;
aa->test();
aa->test();
aa->test();
std::cout << "still works\n";
return a.exec();
}
```

Why doesn't it crash? Why it still continues executing despite destructor was called? When i call `test` method i deal with memory that doesn't belong to the app any more.

What is more surprising is it still works even if I insert `aa = NULL;` right after `delete aa;`. `test` method gets called all right. I need to confess that i'm totally confused. What is the purpose of destructors and assigning NULL if it has no effect?

Comment: Welcome to the realm of _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: `aa->test();` would not work after some time...

Comment: @DimaRudnik that doesn't explain why after `aa = NULL;` it still works.

Comment: @icepack that is why it's a comment...

Comment: @icepack, why not? it just means that `this` is NULL. Which works for most compilers (as long as you don't deference the pointer, you won't notice).

Comment: @DimaRudnik But he is dereferencing it!

Comment: @icepack, where? This isn't a virtual function, so it can be statically linked. Which means that `aa` can be passed silently as the `this` parameter without incurring a terrible segfault.

Comment: @DimaRudnik `aa->test()` is most definitely a dereference

Comment: @icepack, it most definitely is not! It's a method call. Same syntax, but different meaning. The same syntax was chosen to highlight this is a member function accessed via pointer, same way a member field is accessed. But the semantics are woefully different.

Comment: @icepack Why would it be? No vtable lookup is needed. The function to be called is known statically and the `this` pointer just needs to be *passed as argument* in case the method uses it.

Comment: @delnan thanks, that's the real explanation I have been looking for. I should brush up my knowledge, it's been too long...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Why this works?

There are two ways to answer your question:

### Technical Answer:

Your code has an **Undefined Behavior**.
It dereferences a `NULL` or a `delete`ed pointer. As per the C++ standard both invoke Undefined Behavior. It works or not is pointless.
Undefined behavior means that any behavior is possible and it may or may not crash but it means that your program cannot be expected to give any well defined output. It simply means that any behavior is possible and it may not be consistent or well defined.

### Practical Answer:

It doesn't crash because the compiler does not actually derefence `this` while calling member function. Unless the function is an `virtual` function the compiler converts the member function call to a usual function call by passing `this` as the first parameter to the function. It can do so because the compiler can exactly determine which function to call at compile time itself. So practically, calling the member function through deleted or `NULL` pointer does not dereference the `this`(*which is invalid if its `NULL` or `delete`ed*). Further, the `this` is dereferenced only if any member is accessed inside the function body.
In your case you never access any member inside the function body and hence it does not crash.
Add a member and dereference it inside your function and it should definitely crash.

Regardless, of what is said in practical answer technical answer is above and over everything Since standard says that.

Comment: First you say it dereferences a pointer, then you say it doesn't.

Comment: @Pubby: Edited the answer to describe a bit more.Hope it is much more explanatory now.

Answer (score 3):

> Why doesn't it crash?

You are invoking **undefined behaviour** by dereferencing a deleted pointer. Undefined behaviour means your program can do *anything*. Anything includes not crashing.

If undefined behaviour always meant that your program immediately crashed then it would be easy to debug and fix. One of the nastiest problems with undefined behaviour is that the program can appear to work correctly when you test it and then when you ship it to your customers they get unusual behaviour which you are unable to reproduce. You should always avoid invoking undefined behaviour even if things seem to work on your machine.

Comment: that doesn't explain why after `aa = NULL;` it still works.

Comment: @icepack: Dereferencing a null pointer is also undefined behaviour. This again means that the program could do anything including not crashing.

Comment: yes, but dereferencing a null pointer should most definitely yield different results than those of dereferencing `this`. And that's not the case according to OP.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this. The dereferencing isn't some random operation, it's a deterministic computation based on `this` with a corresponding result. In my opinion having the same result for `this` and for null is not a valid compiler output.

Comment: @icepack: Yes that's an interesting opinion, but unfortunately the compiler doesn't care about your opinion. What matters is what the C++ specification says, and the specification says it's undefined behaviour. Therefore the compiler does not have to generate code that will cause a crash if you dereference an invalid pointer.

Comment: My opinion doesn't matter but I would claim that having such behavior is an indication of a more general bug (that might surface for other cases which have defined behavior according to standard)

Comment: A better description would be "calling a member function using an invalid pointer is undefined behavior" to remove confusion about dereferencing (there is none here).

Comment: It's not about the crash, it's about having 2 **different addresses** (null and this) being dereferenced in the same way resulting in the same output.

Comment: @icepack If UB enters the picture, even the code of `gcc` register allocator and the code of Win32's `HeapAlloc` can do the same thing (such as printing `Arr, demons be flying out yet nose!`, or anything else really). As far as the standard is concerned, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

That is just undefined behavior, which includes the possibility of a big crash!

Not much more to say, but a quote from the standard may help on the meaning of **undefined behavior**:

#### 1.3.24 undefined behavior

> behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements [ Note: Undefined
>   behavior may be expected when this International Standard omits any
>   explicit definition of behavior or when a program uses an erroneous
>   construct or erroneous data. Permissible undefined behavior ranges
>   from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to
>   behaving during translation or program execution in a documented
>   manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance
>   of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution
>   (with the issuance of a diagnostic message). Many erroneous program
>   constructs do not engender undefined behavior; they are required to be
>   diagnosed. — end note ]